# Spark jar package dependency file

Tags: apache-spark

I want to do some ip to location computation on spark, after exploring the net ,find IPLocator https://github.com/miraclesu/IPLocator,

the IP to location need to use a file which contains the mapping information.

After packaging the jar, I can run it through on using local java, the package just runs with the `IPLocator.jar` and `qqwry.dat` in the same directory.

But I want to use this jar using spark , I tryed to use `--jars IPLocator.jar qqwry.dat` when starting spark-shell, but when launching , the functions still can not read get the file .

the file reading code is like

```
QQWryFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource("qqwry.dat")
```

I also tried to package  `qqwry.dat` file into the jar, and It did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `--files` and then `SparkFiles.get` inside of your program

Answer (score 0):

Try to use comma delimitor and check if IPLocator.jar and qqwry.dat are distributed to spark staging folder(`.sparkStaging/application_xxx`).

```
--jars IPLocator.jar,qqwry.dat
```